# a weird ExceptionInInitializerError when migrating project to JDK 8

Tags: java, static, nullpointerexception, java-8

I have a code with some binary dependencies ([BioJava](http://biojava.org/wiki/Main_Page) 3.1.0 is the root of the foregoing problem) that works fine with JDK 7, but when using and compiling with JDK 8, something strange happens... Here's the important portion of the stack trace:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.biojava3.core.sequence.template.AbstractSequence.getSequenceAsString(AbstractSequence.java:527)
        at uk.ac.roslin.ensembl.datasourceaware.core.DADNASequence.getSequenceAsString(DADNASequence.java:465)
...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.<init>(Collections.java:1026)
        at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableList.<init>(Collections.java:1302)
        at java.util.Collections.unmodifiableList(Collections.java:1287)
        at org.biojava3.core.sequence.location.template.AbstractLocation.<init>(AbstractLocation.java:111)
        at org.biojava3.core.sequence.location.SimpleLocation.<init>(SimpleLocation.java:57)
        at org.biojava3.core.sequence.location.SimpleLocation.<init>(SimpleLocation.java:53)
...
```

Here is the binary code for `SimpleLocation` (which is in a 3'rd party linked library that I don't have the source to) it has a single field `EMPTY_LOCS` and the construction goes like this:

```
public class SimpleLocation extends AbstractLocation {

    private static final List<Location> EMPTY_LOCS = Collections.emptyList();
    ...
    public SimpleLocation(int start, int end, Strand strand) 
        this(new SimplePoint(start), new SimplePoint(end), strand); { //line 53
    }

    public SimpleLocation(Point start, Point end, Strand strand) { 
        super(start, end, strand, false, false, EMPTY_LOCS); //line 57
    ...
```

Its seems that when `EMPTY_LOCS` is passed to the `super` that is `AbstractLocation` (line: 57), a null is passed and **NOT an empty list** (I checked with JDK 7, and there a good old empty list is passed).

Why is that? Should I just dig into the 3'rd party dependency source code and overwrite it? (not sounds very neat to me)

When I use the `emptyList()` method myself, it **does** return an empty list- but this private static field buried within my dependencies have something against Java 8 and just don't want to be initialized.

**EDIT**:

`AbstractLocation` in turn calls `unmodifiableList()` (line: 111) with null (and **NOT empty list**):

```
public AbstractLocation(Point start, Point end, Strand strand,
        boolean circular, boolean betweenCompounds, AccessionID accession,
        List<Location> subLocations) {
    this.start = start;
    this.end = end;
    this.strand = strand;
    this.circular = circular;
    this.betweenCompounds = betweenCompounds;
    this.accession = accession;
    this.subLocations = Collections.unmodifiableList(subLocations); //line 111
    assertLocation();
}
```

Which then constructs `UnmodifiableList` (line: 1287):

```
public static <T> List<T> unmodifiableList(List<? extends T> list) {
    return (list instanceof RandomAccess ?
            new UnmodifiableRandomAccessList<>(list) :
            new UnmodifiableList<>(list)); //line 1287
}
```

Which calls his `super` (line: 1302):

```
UnmodifiableList(List<? extends E> list) {
    super(list); //line 1302
    this.list = list;
}
```

And because a null is passed to constructor, a `NullPointerException` is thrown (line: 1026):

```
   static class UnmodifiableCollection<E> implements Collection<E>, Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1820017752578914078L;

        final Collection<? extends E> c;

        UnmodifiableCollection(Collection<? extends E> c) {
            if (c==null)
                throw new NullPointerException(); //line 1026
            this.c = c;
        }
```

**This throwing does not happen when using JDK 7**, and No `ExceptionInInitializerError` is happening.

### QUICK FIX:

This was a Maven dependency, so I've reached the source code manually, imported the jar artifact into my own source to overwrite the Maven dependency, and changed `AbstractLocation` in line:111 to wrap with the following:

```
if (subLocations == null) {
    subLocations = Collections.<Location>emptyList();
}
```

But the mystery of non-initialized `private static final` (with empthasize on the `static`) when migrating to JDK8 still bugs me.

Comment: Does the code work under Java 8 when you simply pass new ArrayList<>() in line 57 instead of EMPTY_LOCS? Also, what happens in org.biojava3.core.sequence.location.template.AbstractLocation.<init> (line 111)? Do you have the source code and are able to post it to provide a complete picture?

Comment: So what is your evidence that EMPTY_LOCS is the problem?  What is happening at Abstractequence:527?  Have you tried putting a static initializer in SimpleLocation to verify whether EMPTY_LOCS has been initialized correctly?  What does DADNASequence:465 look like, if you have that?

Comment: @hendrik I edited the question to emphasize that this problem happened on a linked library that I don't have the source to.

Comment: @arcy I appended an edit, hope it helps you to help me

Comment: Well, maybe you have found a bug.  We know that Java 8 infers types of parameters to generics in these situations, perhaps in this particular one, it doesn't do it correctly.  Try using a new operator instead of emptyList(); try using a static initializer block instead of a variable initialization.  Neither of these things should be necessary, but if they work and this doesn't it is evidence of a bug in the implementation behind this construction.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a cycle in class initialization to me.

The rules for class initialization are that a class is initialized before an instance of it is created, and a superclass is initialized before a subclass. The exception is that, during class initialization, if a code path occurs that encounters a class currently being initialized by this thread, the code proceeds *and can observe the partially initialized or uninitialized state of the class.*

Simplifying the example given here, we have

```
public class SimpleLocation extends AbstractLocation {

    private static final List<Location> EMPTY_LOCS = Collections.emptyList();

    public SimpleLocation(...) { 
        super(..., EMPTY_LOCS);
    }
}
```

Given the above rules, it sure looks like `EMPTY_LOCS` must be initialized prior to the constructor calling `super()` on its superclass. But the superclass gets `null` for that parameter and blows up. The only way this can occur is the `SimpleLocation` constructor is called before the class is completely initialized.

Class initialization occurs in declaration order from top to bottom (or left to right, as the spec has it). Even though `EMPTY_LOCS` is final, its initial state of `null` is observable by static initializers declared above it in the class and static initializers of the superclass. For example, this is easy to see if a line like the following were inserted above the declaration of `EMPTY_LOCS`:

```
    static SimpleLocation defaultLocation = new SimpleLocation();
```

I looked at the source for BioJava 3.1 and I didn't see anything like this. It may be that you're using a modified version, or there's some other class initialization dependency that causes this that I haven't thought of.

I doubt there is any Java 7 vs Java 8 specific behavior difference here. It seems more likely that there is something else about the difference between 7 and 8 that is causing your system to take a different code path, and this ends up changing the order of class initialization from some way that just luckily happened to work, to a way that causes this error to occur.

If you want to trace the order of class loading and initialization, run the system with the option `-verbose:class`.

Answer (score 0):

This does seem to be a static initialisation cycle as explained in [a prior answer by Stuart Marks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28935827/4975843). The cycle is probably because the child class is referenced in a static initialiser of one of the interfaces it implements:

```
public interface Location extends Iterable<Location>, Accessioned {

    /**
     * Basic location which is set to the minimum and maximum bounds of
     * {@link Integer}. {@link Strand} is set to {@link Strand#UNDEFINED}.
     */
    public static final Location EMPTY =
        new SimpleLocation(Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE, Strand.UNDEFINED);
    ...
}
```

So we have a situation where Location requires SimpleLocation to be initialised and SimpleLocation requires Location to be initialised. The cycle has to be broken somehow, and it appears that JDK8 is resolving it differently to JDK7 and earlier.

I was able to break the cycle with a simple trick: by referencing the Location.EMPTY field directly prior to any reference of the child class, it causes it to initialise in a different order. I'm not sure if this solution is reliable, it might be that the order is still arbitrary. However at least it does seem to work in JDK8 without modifying any of the third party libraries:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // This line prevents exception on the next line        
    Location l = Location.EMPTY;

    // This line will fail if the line above is commented out
    SimpleLocation s = new SimpleLocation(20,30, Strand.POSITIVE, new SimpleLocation[0]);
}
```